# React/Firebase - How to make sure an update happens before redirect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, session

In my app, users can sign up with their email address and password (all with Firebase) and by default the user's wont have their `displayName` and `photoURL` set if they sign up with email/password. Which is why I'm trying to update their profile in the moment they submit the sign up form by adding those 2 fields.

After a successful sign up, the users get redirected to the protected Home page where I'm trying to display, you guessed it, their `displayName` and photo (`photoURL`) BUT, even if I set those fields, the Home page doesn't pick it up on time and I always have to refresh the page for those details to appear.

Can I have some help with this please?\

```
onSubmit = event => {
    const { displayName, photoURL, email, passwordOne } = this.state;
    const { history } = this.props; /* eslint-disable-line */

    authFunctions
        .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
        .then(session => {
            auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
                displayName,
                photoURL
            });
            db.doCreateUser(session.user.uid, displayName, photoURL, email)
                .then(() => {
                    this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
                    history.push(routes.HOME);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
                });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState(byPropKey('error', error));
        });

    event.preventDefault();
};
```

As you can see on my code, I'm creating the users on Firebase and then adding them to the database as well. I'm trying to update the profiles right after I create the actual user but for some reason it doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the Firebase User profile and creating the user profile in the database simultaneously. It is most likely routing to the home screen before the update can finish.

```
return auth.currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName, photoURL }).then(() => {
    db.doCreateUser(session.user.uid, displayName, photoURL, email).then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        history.push(routes.HOME);
    })
})
```

Add a then after updating the Firebase User and 'then' create the user profile in the database.

Comment: This one actually works with the Home Page thanks! Now only the navigation component is lagging behind. Would it help if I added a short wait before redirecting? Say, 2 seconds?